# Sequence of marching chars in 2 strings

Tags: c#

I have to write searching algorithm, For example I have to compare `str="giorgi"` to `str2="grigol"`. I'm trying to find longest matching sequence of chars, so that the order of chars is the same and string which I should get is `"grg"`... with this c# code I'm getting `"grig"`.

```
int k=0;
        string s="";
        string str = "giorgi";
        string str2 = "grigol";
        for(int i=0;i<str.Length;i++)
        {
            for (int j = k; j < str2.Length; j++)
            {
                if (str[i] == str2[j])
                {
                    s += str2[k];
                    k++;
                    goto endofloop;
                }

            }
        endofloop:;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Comment: First thing you should do is remove the `goto` and **never use it again**.  You should also look at the `break` statement because that seems like what you will want instead.

Comment: I tried it did't work

Comment: Trying to understand the question. How would you get "grg"? The strings have only the starting "g" in common right? None of the other letters are in same position in both strings.

Comment: so there is "giorgi" and "grigol"
first match is "g", second match is "r"...

Comment: I'm trying to compare all the chars of "giorgi" to each letter of "grigol" so that: g = g, i!=r,o!=r, but r!=r

Comment: r=r I mean, then it should jump to "g" and compare it to "i" and then compare it to "g" somehow

Comment: I agree with @NimishDavidMathew - how do you get `grg`?

Comment: Why is the second match "r" and not "i"?

Comment: Following your logic, you should match `i` after matching `gr`. I guess, you have [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Any reason why `gio` is not a valid match?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution:

```
using System; 
class GFG 
{ 

    /* Returns length of LCS for X[0..m-1], Y[0..n-1] */
    static int lcs( char[] X, char[] Y, int m, int n ) 
    { 
        int [,]L = new int[m+1,n+1]; 

        /* Following steps build L[m+1][n+1]  
        in bottom up fashion. Note 
        that L[i][j] contains length of  
        LCS of X[0..i-1] and Y[0..j-1] */
        for (int i = 0; i <= m; i++) 
        { 
            for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++) 
            { 
                if (i == 0 || j == 0) 
                    L[i, j] = 0; 
                else if (X[i - 1] == Y[j - 1]) 
                    L[i, j] = L[i - 1, j - 1] + 1; 
                else
                    L[i, j] = GFG.max(L[i - 1, j], L[i, j - 1]); 
            } 
        } 
        return L[m, n]; 
    }

    static int max(int a, int b) 
    { 
        return (a > b)? a : b; 
    } 
}
```

> And now the program to test it:

```
    public static void Main() 
    { 

        String s1 = "giorgi"; 
        String s2 = "grigol"; 

        char[] X=s1.ToCharArray(); 
        char[] Y=s2.ToCharArray(); 
        int m = X.Length; 
        int n = Y.Length; 

        Console.Write("Length of LCS is" + " " +lcs( X, Y, m, n ) ); 
    } 
}
```